# Matching List of Numbers (with Duplicates) to Strings in another Column

Tags: excel, list, match

I have two large lists of numbers, one with duplicates and one without:

First list: 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, ...

Second list: 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9,...

Now, for each unique number on the second list, there is another column with an identifier for that number. Example: 2 = A, 3 = B, 4 = C, 5 = D, 7 = E, etc.

What I want to do is match up the unique identifiers on the first list with those on the second:

New list: 2A, 2A, 3B, 3B, 3B, 3B, 4C, 5D, 7E, 7E, 7E, etc.

Is there an easy way to do this? My list has thousands of values so I cannot manually match them up.

Here is an example of my spreadsheet:

Column A--Column B--Column C
----2-------------2-------------A
----2-------------3-------------B
----3-------------4-------------C
----3-------------5-------------D
----3-------------7-------------E
----3-------------8-------------F
----4-------------9-------------G

What I want is this:

Column A--Column B
----2--------------A
----2--------------A
----3--------------B
----3--------------B
----3--------------B
----3--------------B
----4--------------C
----5--------------D
etc.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. I am sorry if I wasn't clear with my request. Please let me know if you need clarification.

Thanks!

Comment: In your example spreadsheet, is Column A the first list that you refer to earlier and Column B the second list?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, here is what you want:

```
=A2&VLOOKUP(A2,B:C,2,FALSE)
```

This assumes that column A is your list with duplicates and columns B and C are your unique numbers paired with their corresponding letters.

You can then drag the formula down to apply to all values in column A.